# Python Lambda Count/Loop Function

Tags: python, lambda

I'm sorry if this is a question answered elsewhere.  Searching through Google and Stackforum I didn't find anything from which I could extrapolate the answers; but I feel like part of that is me.

I'm trying to work out lambdas as a concept, and as part of that I'm kinda looking for ways to use it.

SO, if this is a colossally stupid thing to do with lambda from a function standpoint, feel free to let me know and explain.  But either way, I still want to know the answer/still want to know how to do this with the python language.

So, for testing purposes I have:

```
my_test = 'test_name'
testlist = ['test_name', 'test_name_dup', 'test_name_dup_1', 'test_name_dup_3']
```

I'm looking to use lambda to create one function that loops through and returns the first test_name_# that isn't in the testlist.  The functionality will eventually be applied to filenames, but for testing purposes I had to get away from actually reading the filenames--gave me too many more ways to mess something up.

But my_test has to be able to change, and the test list will be a list of filepaths.

So, I'm looking for a function like:

```
new_name = lambda x: my_test + '_' + str(x)
```

But the initial value should be x = 1, and it should continue until new_name is not in testlist.  Seems like:

```
bool(new_name not in testlist)
```

might be something work with.

But I can't figure out a way to set the initial x to 1, and have it loop through with (x+1) until the bool is true.

I know this is possible as I've found some CRAZY lambda examples out there that are looping through lines in a file.  I just couldn't quite make sense of them (and didn't have any way to play with them as they were dealing with things outside my programming level.

On a related note, could I add values to the beginning of this loop?  (i.e. can I have it check for test_name, then test_name_dup, then test_name_dup_#)?

Thanks in advance for the help!  Lambdas (while very cool) totally mess with my head.

Comment: Could you provide more examples of inputs and outputs for this target function?

Comment: Note that the crazy `lambda` examples may just be bad examples as `lambda`s are not meant for lots of code because they make code unreadable and using a normal function is a lot better in most situations.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you told us what the correct result would be for the my_test/testlist example.

Comment: Yea, a lot of them were definitely "crazy"; a lot of them were even people saying they were crazy lambdas; just showing it could be done.

Comment: @bereal I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for.  my_test is just what I'm using to test for any possible filename.  So the possible imputs could be anything from "A.html" to "Changelog.php" to "Xenophobia in the U.S. During World War I.docx" (I'd be splitting the filename from the extension elsewhere; so this would be combining the output of my filename(f) with these "dup"s and then adding my extension(f) (os.splittext wasn't quite good enough as I wanted to be able to deal with ".partXX.rars" and folders.

Comment: @RobinHood well, what I mean is that I'm failing to understand what the function is supposed to do (someone else might have understood better). Maybe, you could provide the same functionality without lambda as an explanation, or give more examples of what it takes and what it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use a `lambda` in this case, a simple `for` loop will do:

```
my_test  = 'test_name_dup'  
testlist = ['test_name', 'test_name_dup','test_name_dup_1', 'test_name_dup_3']

for i in xrange(1, len(testlist)):
    if my_test + '_' + str(i) not in testlist:
        break

print my_test + '_' + str(i)
> test_name_dup_2
```

If you really, really want to use a `lambda` for this problem, you'll also have to learn about itertools, iterators, filters, etc. I'm gonna build on thg435's answer, writing it in a more idiomatic fashion and explaining it:

```
import itertools as it

iterator = it.dropwhile(
    lambda n: '{0}_{1}'.format(my_test, n) in testlist,
    it.count(1))

print my_test + '_' + str(iterator.next())
> test_name_dup_2
```

The key to understanding the above solution lies in the [`dropwhile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) procedure. It takes two parameters: a predicate and an iterable, and returns an iterator that drops elements from the iterable as long as the predicate is true; afterwards, returns every element.

For the iterable, I'm passing `count(1)`, an iterator that produces an infinite number of integers starting from `1`.

Then `dropwhile()` starts to consume the integers until the predicate is false; this is a good opportunity for passing an in-line defined function - and here's our `lambda`. It receives each generated integer in turn, checking to see if the string test_name_dup_# is present in the list.

When the predicate returns `false`, `dropwhile()` returns and we can retrieve the value that made it stop by calling `next()` on it.

Comment: `xrange(1, len(testlist))` is not necessarily enough, is it?

Comment: Yea, but as I said I'm looking to understand how to do this with lambda; even if it's not necessary.  I have an iterator function that does this with just yields.  With three lines I can get this it iteraltools.count and have it check the first two.

Comment: @RobinHood but your example is like trying to fit a square peg in a round hole, it's really, really not what lambdas are good for. It would lead to an extremely contrived solution. Take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/python-lambda-why) for ideas on when it's appropriate to use a `lambda`

Comment: @LevLevitsky I believe it's enough; can you come up with a counterexample?

Comment: @LevLevitsky anyway, I replaced my `xrange` with an infinite iterator, that should be enough now :)

Comment: @Óscar nevermind, `len(testlist)` was enough. Thanks for an infinite iterator example, though :)

Comment: @RobinHood there you have it, a well-explained solution using a lambda.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Wow, I'm looking through all the answers and this is the best by far (and thanks for helping me work out what the lambda was doing).  I'm still looking at Winston's code--seems like I need to alter it to work with what I'm doing, but looks promising.  My problem with this code is I can't see how to adapt it to use "my_test" (a stand in for any variety of filenames) as the base instead of fixed "test_name_dup_" text/string.  I'll be looking at it, but I'm not sure I'm gonna be able to see how it would be done.

Comment: @RobinHood I edited my answer to use `my_test`, it should be easy to see how you can fiddle with `format` to adapt it to your file names, just remember that the positional parameters `{0}, {1}, ...` get replaced by the arguments to `format()` in the same order

Answer (score 6):

Lambdas are just another way of defining a function

```
def foo(x):
    return x + x
```

is the same as

```
foo = lambda x: x + x
```

So let's start with a function to do what you want:

```
def first_missing(items, base):
    for number in itertools.count():
        text = base + '_' + str(number)
        if text not in items:
             return text
```

The first thing to note is that you can't use loops inside a lambda. So we'll need to rewrite this without a loop. Instead, we'll use recursion:

```
def first_missing(items, base, number = 0):
        text = base + '_' + str(number)
        if text not in items:
             return text
        else:
             return first_missing(items, base, number + 1)
```

Now, we also can't use an if/else block in a lambda. But we can use a ternary expression:

```
def first_missing(items, base, number = 0):
        text = base + '_' + str(number)
        return text if text not in items else first_missing(items, base, number + 1)
```

We can't have local variables in a lambda, so we'll use a trick, default arguments:

```
def first_missing(items, base, number = 0):
        def inner(text = base + '_' + str(number)):
            return text if text not in items else first_missing(items, base, number + 1)
        return inner()
```

At this point we can rewrite inner as a lambda:

```
def first_missing(items, base, number = 0):
        inner = lambda text = base + '_' + str(number): text if text not in items else first_missing(items, base, number + 1)
        return inner()
```

We can combine two lines to get rid of the inner local variable:

```
def first_missing(items, base, number = 0):
    return (lambda text = base + '_' + str(number): text if text not in items else first_missing(items, base, number + 1))()
```

And at long last, we can make the whole thing into a lambda:

```
first_missing = lambda: items, base, number = 0: (lambda text = base + '_' + str(number): text if text not in items else first_missing(items, base, number + 1))()
```

Hopefully that gives you some insight into what you can do. But don't ever do it because, as you can tell, lambdas can make your code really hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine a lambda with itertools.dropwhile:

```
import itertools
n = itertools.dropwhile(lambda n: 'test_name_dup_%d' % n in testlist, range(1, len(testlist))).next()
```

As to your last question, you can write a generator for names, like:

```
def possible_names(prefix):
    yield prefix
    yield prefix + '_dup'
    n = 0
    while True:
        n += 1
        yield '%s_dup_%d' % (prefix, n)
```

and then use this generator with dropwhile:

```
unique_name = itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x in testlist, possible_names('test_name')).next()
print unique_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You are a bit off the track. Lambdas are nothing but "simple" functions, often used for their fast syntax in functional programming. They are the perfect companion built-in functions "map", "reduce", "filter" but also for more complicated functions defined into [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html). Therefore the most useful thing to do with them is to generate/manipulate iterable objects (especially lists). Note that lambdas will slow down your code in most of the cases if compared to list comprehensions/normal loops and will make it harder to be read. Here is an example of what you want to do with lambdas.

```
>>> filter(lambda i: i!=(0 if len(testlist[i].split("_"))==3 else int(testlist[i].split("_")[-1])), range(len(testlist)))[0]
2
```

Or you could use more complicated functions with itertools. Anyhow I strongly suggest you not to use lambdas for this kind of assignments, as the readability is terrible. I'd rather use a well structured for loop, which is also faster.

**[Edit]**

To prove that lambdas+builtins are not faster than list comprehensions: consider a simple problem, for x in range(1000) create a list of x shifted by 5.

$ python -m timeit 'map(lambda x: x>>5, range(1000))' 1000 loops, best of 3: **225 usec** per loop

$ python -m timeit '[x>>5 for x in range(1000)]'10000 loops, best of 3: **99.1 usec** per loop

You have a >100% performance increase without lambdas.

Comment: My understanding is that if it's going to be nested, lambdas can provide a speed benefit to some other loops.  Haven't found something that really let me understand the difference.  This lambda function is meant to be nested in a function to merge/move folders/files in certain circumstances.  The reason it seemed like a good enough choice for me to at least figure some of the functionality of lambdas out is that this isn't going to be something to be improved/changed/etc.  It's going to be in charge of naming stuff when there's going to be two of something in the same place.

Comment: Software should be readable, not optimized for size. Leave that to the CPU and optimizers. If code is not readable by your entire team, it is definitely a bug in the code. The opposite is true, if code is simple and readable, people will like your software. Above code will not pass my reviews highlikely.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the list comprehension or iterator method.  Makes for easy one liners that I feel are pretty easy to read and maintain. Quite frankly, lambdas belong some places, here I believe its less elegant a solution.

```
my_test = 'test_name'
prefix = 'test_name_dup_'
testlist = ['test_name','test_name_dup','test_name_dup_1','test_name_dup_3']

from itertools import count
print next('%s%d' % (prefix, i) for i in count(1) if '%s%d' % (prefix, i) not in testlist)
```

This returns the first not-found instance in the sequence, which I think is the cleanest.

Of course, if you prefer a list from a definite range, you can modify it to become a list comprehension:

```
print ['%s%d' % (prefix, i) for i in xrange(0,5) if '%s%d' % (prefix, i) not in testlist]
```

returns:

```
['test_name_dup_0', 'test_name_dup_2', 'test_name_dup_4']
```